# TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into a Tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Following is my code using tensorflow, and I have been trying to debug this error for two days...

```
changed_result = y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: pixelNew, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

and:

```
changed_result = tf.Variable([0.0],tf.float32)
```

I have tried making changed_result a tensor or just not declaring it. Both won't work.

Below is the whole error description:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "deepMnist.py", line 235, in 
>       tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
>
> File "/Users/ximinlin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>
> File "deepMnist.py", line 162, in main
>       changed_result = y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: pixelNew, keep_prob: 1.0})
>   File "/Users/ximinlin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 575, in eval
>       return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
>
> File "/Users/ximinlin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3633, in _eval_using_default_session
>       return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
>
> File "/Users/ximinlin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File "/Users/ximinlin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 921, in _run
>       + e.args[0])
>   TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into a Tensor.

Following is definition of x and keep_pro:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

keep_prob = 0
```

keep_prob, and x are actually code from tensorflow tutorial, and I just copy them to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing enough context to give a very concrete answer, but your error is that either `x` or `keep_prob` are not tensors, but an integer at the point where you call it (you might have overwritten them, if you defined them as tensors before).

So, the error is with `x` or `keep_prob`, not with `changed_result`.

Comment: x is a tensor, keep_prob is not tensor. However, when in the code they did:
       train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        there is no error.

Comment: If you are referring to the deep mnist example, keep_prob **is** a tensor in the example. `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)`